# create xml with jdom, how to set standalone="no" attribute

Tags: java, xml, jdom

When I create a jdom document (Document doc = new Document();), by default I only see version and encoding in the xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

How can I add the standalone attribute to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Header is normally stripped by the XMLParser before the document gets to JDOM. I'm pretty sure you mean you're looking at the **output** from JDOM, which adds the XML declaration back in.

You can adjust how the XML Declaration is processed by creating a [custom XMLOutput processor](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/output/support/AbstractXMLOutputProcessor.java)... with this custom class, override the printDeclaration method and change it to do what you need....

```
public static final XMLOutputProcessor XMLOUTPUT = new AbstractXMLOutputProcessor() {
    @Override
    protected void printDeclaration(final Writer out, final FormatStack fstack) throws IOException {
        write(out, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" standalone=\"no\"?> ");
        write(out, fstack.getLineSeparator());
    }
};
```

Then, when you want to use this, you pass it to your XMLOutputter as:

```
XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat(), XMLOUTPUT);
xout.output(doc, System.out);
```

It is apparent that the mechanism for doing this is rather cumbersome. I will look in to what alternatives there are, and perhaps fix this in a future version.

Comment: As said in the answer, do we have an alternate to this solution available now ?