# I want to add xml declaration by using JDOM

Tags: xml, jdom-2

My code is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
        try {
            //System.out.println(doc);
            outputter.output(doc, System.out);       
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

My expectation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://abc/test_automation/logfile.xsl"?>
```

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a second processing instruction for the `xml-stylesheet`?. If you want one, you can add one using the `doc.addContent(new ProcessingInstruction(....))`

Comment: Additionally, if you want `standalone="no"` - please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21177465/1305253

Comment: Thank u Rolfl. I am able to add standalone="no". But for <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://abc/test_automation/logfile.xsl"?> Can you give me some hint..?